# How to iterate two non-equal 2D array using Stream

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, functional-programming, java-stream

I am very new to Stream,How can I achieve the below code snippet using Stream?

```
private String iterateRadioButtons(JRadioButton[][] jButtons) {
        boolean status = false;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int row = 0; row < jButtons.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < jButtons[row].length; col++) {
                if(jButtons[col][row] != null && jButtons[col][row].isSelected()){
                    sb.append(jButtons[col][row].getName());
                    status = true;
                }
                if(col == jButtons[i].length-1 && !status){
                    throw new RuntimeException("Please fill all Radio Buttons");
                }
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Anyone can you please help me, i'm not getting any idea how to remove the above code snippet using Stream.Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: what's the peculiar `if(col == jButtons[i].length-1 && !status)` condition for? should it be `if(col <= jButtons[i].length-1 && !status)` instead or much simplified `else { throw new RuntimeException("Please fill all Radio Buttons");}`? A general hint to stream could be using something like `return Arrays.stream(jButtons)
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .filter(jRadioButton -> jRadioButton != null && jRadioButton.isSelected())
                .map(JRadioButton::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());`

Comment: @Naman : Basically the condition if(col == jButtons[i].length-1 && !status) means if any Radio button from each column he miss then it won't allow to proceed further and throw RuntimeException.

Comment: Any way the solution is working except that condition check. Thanks @Naman !!!!